# Вопрос для знатоков jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$('input.input-qty').mouseover(function(){
        $(this)
      });
```

Что нужно дописать после $(this), чтобы при наведении мышкой на input он выделился, точнее его содержимое? Тот же эффект достигается если сделать двойной щелчок мышкой по полю ввода.

[image: Выбранный input]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(this).select()